# How to make a responsive scrollable navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar, responsive

I am trying to make a responsive navbar where part of the items become scrollable when the screen size is reduced. It is something like this:

Large screens:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  FIXED ITEM +               EMPTY SPACE               + SCROLLABLE ITEM + FIXED ITEM +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Small screens:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| FIXED ITEM | SCROLLABL... | FIXED ITEM |
+++++++++++++.<@@@@>--------.+++++++++++++
```

So far, I have managed to do everything (see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ybfw58s3/)) except the scroll part. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force your text to stay on 1 line with the `white-space: nowrap` property.

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-start {
  margin: 10px;  
}
.navbar-end {
  margin: 10px;
}

.navbar-scrollable {
  background: tomato;
  margin: 10px;

  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
<div class="navbar-start">
FIXED
</div>
<div class="navbar-scrollable">
+++++++++++ SCROLLABLE CONTENT +++++++++++
</div>
<div class="navbar-end">
FIXED
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{ font-family: impact; }
    
.header {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

.logo { 
    
    font-size: 28px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.button {
    width: 80px;
    display: flex;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: cornflowerblue;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.button:hover{

    color: red;
    background-color: white;

}

.at-right{
    
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 380px;
    height:32px;
    background: rgb(0, 191, 255);
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

.scrollnav{ margin: 0 auto; }

.right-side{ display: flex; }

.at-right::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; /* for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <nav class="header">
        <div class="logo">LOGO</div>

        <div class="right-side">
        <div class="at-right">
            
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>
            <div class="scrollnav"> >>>>>> SCROLLABLE CONTENT <<<<<< </div>

        </div>
        
        <a class="button" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
    </div>

    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

just try this example.
and look details for 'hidden scroll bar', 'only y scroll', and 'wrap' etc.